# Finding radius of a frustum Cone

Tags: geometry

I am given r1,r2,h,p. Now I need to find the radius k. Can someone help with this problem? I am not really good with geometry.Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Starting out with "I'm not really good at geometry" is a great way to convince people that they do not want to help you. The hope is that you will get better at geometry and at math in general, and you do that by working on the subject -- not by acting helpless and getting other people to do work for you.

So here's a hint how to get started: Extend the central altitude of your cone and the slanted side of your cone until they meet at some point which will be the vertex of the cone. Let x be the (unknown) amount that you extended the central altitude. Now you have several similar triangles.

Comment: Continued hint: Write the equal ratios from two sets of similar triangles. Note that the numerators will be sums, not single letters. Do some algebra to eliminate x. Then solve for the quantity you need.